# Create two environmental variables with one RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, environment-variables

I have query strings like:

```
?request=/de/name/dieter
```

Using the below rule I catch the last part (dieter) and store it as an environmental variable. I'd also like to be able to store the first part of the URL (de) as an environmental variable, but I can't find a way to do that. Is it possible.

Rule at current:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^request=([a-z\/]*)name\/(.*?)([^/]{3})([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=N:%2%3/%4]
RewriteRule .* - [E=LANG:%1]
```

Comment: Does it not work to `[E=N:%2%3/%4,E=LANG:%1]` ?

Comment: Yes it does. I tried that but must have had an error as I got a 500 error. If you post this as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the "rewrite flags" `[]` portion of a `RewriteRule` accepts a comma-separated list of flags, and [the `RewriteRule` docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) do not explicitly say that you may not repeat a flag. Since `E=` is a flag, it should work to provide a comma-separated list of `E=` along with other rewrite flags (like `[L]` if needed)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^request=([a-z\/]*)name\/(.*?)([^/]{3})([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=N:%2%3/%4,E=LANG:%1]
```